# mobile AIR app - Any logging api that can write to file?

Tags: file, mobile, logging, air, adobe

for a flash AIR app, are there any logging api that can do log to file, later can be sent back via email or something for troubleshooting?  The issue is the end user will not be able to connect to debuggers.

Comment: I personally have used Google Analytics for this in the past, though that isn't very efficient for bandwidth on the end-user

Comment: ok, I will check that out.  All I want is the log should be in the android/ios mobile, on demand when issues occur, the app should be able to email it back.